# web.py - How to turn result of db.query(sql) into list of dict?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm new to both Python and web.py (which I am currently using) so please bear with me.

In [the official document](http://webpy.org/cookbook/query):

```
import web
db = web.database(dbn='postgres', db='mydata', user='dbuser', pw='')
results = db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_users FROM users")
print results[0].total_users # -> prints number of entries in 'users' table
```

Looks like the result of the query is a list of dictionaries {total_user: num} right?

My situation is very similar: running a SELECT against the database, hoping to get a list of key:value data.

In models.py:

```
def get_items:
    return self.db.query("SELECT title FROM news")
```

In code.py:

```
items = model.get_items
return render.list(items)
```

In templates/list.html:

```
$def with (items)
$for item in items:
    <p>$item.title</p>
```

However, the code triggers an error as "'tuple' object has no attribute 'title'".
What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like there is an error in `get_items` function definition and call. It should be `def get_items()` and `items = model.get_items()`.

Answer (score 0):

It will trigger, because you are just selecting only the title attribute from news, which obvioulsy will give tuple like (a,b,c,d) as result. 
if you want a object as result,do something like  this

```
self.db.query("SELECT * FROM news")
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul, but actually I simplified the query to save space. In the original query, multiple fields (including title of course) are selected, and the result is still the same. It's important to note that I was using MySQLdb. Switching to Postgres eliminates the problem - result is returned as dictionaries correctly.